# "Unable to locate persister" Error with Spring batch + Hibernate ORM

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to create a system with Spring batch using Hibernate ORM but can't solve this Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reader' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]: Factory method 'reader' threw exception with message: Unable to locate persister: com.example.batchprocessing.model.PersonTest1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:488) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchProcessingApplication.main(BatchProcessingApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
```

[This is how my project looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWOBz.png)

These are my setting files.

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>batch-processing-complete</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>batch-processing-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "https://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection properties - Driver, URL, user, password -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        
        <!-- org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        
        <!-- Mapping with model class containing annotations -->
        <mapping class="com.example.batchprocessing.model.PersonTest1" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

PersonTest1.java
Notthing special here.

```
package com.example.batchprocessing.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="people")
public class PersonTest1 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="person_id", nullable=false, unique=true, length=11)
    private int personId;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    public int getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(int personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java
I just copied this from internet so hope there is no problem here.

```
package com.example.batchprocessing.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.example.batchprocessing.JobCompletionNotificationListener;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);
    
    //Annotation based configuration
    private static SessionFactory sessionAnnotationFactory;
    
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionAnnotationFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml");
            log.info("--- Hibernate Configuration loaded ---");
            
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            log.info("--- Hibernate Annotation serviceRegistry created ---");
            
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            
            return sessionFactory;
            
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            log.error("--- Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    
    public static SessionFactory getSessionAnnotationFactory() {
        sessionAnnotationFactory = buildSessionAnnotationFactory();
        
        return sessionAnnotationFactory;
    }
}
```

BatchConfiguration.java
reader() is where I am trying to write to DB.

```
package com.example.batchprocessing;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.example.batchprocessing.model.PersonTest1;
import com.example.batchprocessing.util.HibernateUtil;

@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);

    // tag::readerwriterprocessor[]
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        
        PersonTest1 personTest = new PersonTest1();
        personTest.setLastName("John");
        personTest.setFirstName("Wick");
        
        // Get Session
        log.info("--- Creating session ---");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        
        log.info("--- Starting transaction ---");
        session.beginTransaction();
        
        log.info("--- Saving model ---");
        session.persist(personTest);
        
        log.info("--- Commiting transaction ---");
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        
        log.info("--- Closing session ---");
        sessionFactory.close();
        
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
            .name("personItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
            .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                setTargetType(Person.class);
            }})
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();
    }
    // end::readerwriterprocessor[]

    // tag::jobstep[]
    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobRepository jobRepository,
            JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return new JobBuilder("importUserJob", jobRepository)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository,
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
            .<Person, Person> chunk(10, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }
    // end::jobstep[]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in HibernateUtil is problematic because `applySettings` will only apply properties but no mappings:

```java
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
        .build();
```

Judging from the implementation of `Configuration.configure(String resource)`, you need to call `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(String resource)` to apply the mappings declared in hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml:

```java
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .configure("hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml")
        .build();
```

Or, if you don't actually have a reason to create the ServiceRegistry yourself, instead call `configuration.buildSessionFactory()` and let the Configuration class use the internal StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.

Comment: I tried the first one of your solution and it worked!!
Thank you so much!